# Query completed with an empty output in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create a tracker for finance. I am facing issue where in the below query is working fine and bring the data from the other sheet tab. Basically, the query I am passing month and year for which the data should be fetched. I want to user to type month in the cell and query should take that reference and get data. However, when i am passing reference of the cell in the query for month and year, it is saying Query completed with an empty output.

Below Working fine:

```
=QUERY('Daily Journal'!A2:E18,"SELECT * where Month(A)+1= 9 and Year(A)=2023",0)
```

Below gives error with no data:

```
=QUERY('Daily Journal'!A2:E18,"SELECT * where Month(A)+1= '"&A3&"' and Year(A)=2023",0)
```

I am expecting that month value should be taken from the cell reference A3 directly in query and should show data accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Try without the single quotation marks. That way you're converting A3 in a string:

```
=QUERY('Daily Journal'!A2:E18,"SELECT * where Month(A)+1= "&A3&" and Year(A)=2023",0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same idea as @[Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20363318/mart%C3%ADn), enclosing a value with single quotation marks after an operator tells the query to treat that as a string.

Looking at your working sample, you are using an integer or a numerical value in your WHERE clause hence your query returned empty when pointing it to '"&A3&"'. Just keep the value in cell A3 in numeric format to ensure Martin's query will always work.